# Google Colab TensorFlow model.fit() error

Tags: python, tensorflow

Hi Im new to Stack overflow. Im having trouble with my code, I was at model.fit() and when I entered a value at the epochs and ran the code I got an error. Here is the code for the model.fit:

model.fit(
train_ds,
validation_data = valid_ds,
epochs = 10
)

and below here is the error I got:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
2     train_ds,
3     validation_data = valid_ds,
----> 4     epochs = 10
5 )

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
1145           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
1146             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1147               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
1148             else:
1149               raise

ValueError: in user code:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 859, in train_step
    y_pred = self(x, training=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 305, in compute_output_shape
    f'One of the dimensions in the output is <= 0 '

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential_3" (type Sequential).

One of the dimensions in the output is <= 0 due to downsampling in conv2d_280. Consider increasing the input size. Received input shape [None, 32, 32, 3] which would produce output shape with a zero or negative value in a dimension.

Call arguments received:
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 32, 32, 3), dtype=float32)
  • training=True
  • mask=None
```

Can someone assist me with this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to upscale the size of your image which you are feeding into the CNN. 360x360x3 is a standard one. Your image size is too small, hence it is not able to build the model fully.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering quickly, can you assist me on how to do that? Im quite new to using tensorflow